# How to add extra fields in Registration Form?

Tags: layout, forms, register

How can I add a **paragraph** and **extra fields** in Registration Form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.VG-SJ_nF9Zo and using its Module Creator to create a new module called "YourCustomerAttribute".

1. Set "Add Customer Attribute" to YES
2. Make proper inputs and selections as you needed.
3. Make sure to select the forms you needed the new attributes to be used.
4. Generate the module.
5. Upload the module to your Magento folder.
6. Modify  located at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml and add:

   ```
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="YourAttributeName"><?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?><span class="required">*</span></label><br />
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="YourAttributeName" id="YourAttributeID" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getYourAttributeName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" ></textarea>
   </div>
   ```
7. If you want customer to be able to modify the attribute in customer panel, then modify app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtm and add:

   ```
   <li>
       <label for="YourAttributeName" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
           <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="YourAttributeName" id="YourAttributeID" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getYourAttributeName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" ></textarea>
       </div>
   </li>
   ```
8. Refresh all caches.

Comment: Which Magento version(s) is this compatible with?

Comment: Its customization so u can use above 1.5 version

Comment: How would `<select>` options be added to the HTML?

Comment: I am confused how we can implement this thing,

Comment: In the short term, it is possible to add the options to the .phtml file, but if anyone knows how to get the options to display automatically that'd help.

Comment: Don't tell people to change core code.