# validating is_unique property for custom attribute in customer registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, module, customer, mysql

I've followed this [answer@stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45620/how-to-add-extra-fields-in-registration-form) to create a new attribute (called mobile) for the customer entity.

I was able to create an input field in the registration form(customer_account_create) and able to save the entered value in `customer_entity_varchar` table associated with the `attribute_id` (mobile)

Now, I wanted like to make this attribute unique i.e no user can register for another account using same mobile number. To achieve this, I modified the `msql4-install-0.1.0.php` file at 
(app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/sql/customerattribute_setup/...php)

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile",  array(
    ....
    "unique"     => true,
    ...

    ));
```

By changing the property from false to true. 
The new customer attribute has `is_unique=1` in the `eav_attribute` table.

However, the unique constrain does not apply for some reason when I try to create a new user from the registration form using different email ID but same mobile number (associated to attribute - mobile).

Do I have to do something else so that I can allow users creation only if the said attribute is not associated to any other user ??

Answer (score 1):

The customer attributes has no is_unique option which is available for product attributes